# How to shift image horizontally to create loop effect?

Tags: cocoa, nsimage, cifilter

How to shift NSImage horizontally that shifted pixels appear at the other side so it looks like a loop?
Currently I am using drawInRect. Is there any CIFilter or smarter way to do this?

[image: looped world map]

```
- (CIImage *)image:(NSImage *)image shiftedBy:(CGFloat)shiftAmount
{

    NSUInteger width = image.size.width;
    NSUInteger height = image.size.height;
    NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:NULL
                                                  pixelsWide:width
                                                  pixelsHigh:height
                                               bitsPerSample:8
                                             samplesPerPixel:4
                                                    hasAlpha:YES
                                                    isPlanar:NO
                                              colorSpaceName:NSDeviceRGBColorSpace
                                                 bytesPerRow:0
                                                bitsPerPixel:0];
    [rep setSize:NSMakeSize(width, height)];
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    NSGraphicsContext *context = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithBitmapImageRep:rep];
    [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:context];


    CGRect rect0 = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    CGRect leftSourceRect, rightSourceRect;
    CGRectDivide(rect0, &leftSourceRect, &rightSourceRect, shiftAmount, CGRectMinXEdge);
    CGRect rightDestinationRect = CGRectOffset(leftSourceRect, width - rightSourceRect.origin.x, 0);
    CGRect leftDestinationRect = rightSourceRect;
    leftDestinationRect.origin.x = 0;

    [image drawInRect:leftDestinationRect fromRect:rightSourceRect operation:NSCompositingOperationSourceOver fraction:1.0];
    [image drawInRect:rightDestinationRect fromRect:leftSourceRect operation:NSCompositingOperationSourceOver fraction:1.0];

    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
    return [[CIImage alloc] initWithBitmapImageRep:rep];
}
```

Comment: It looks like you could probably use [`CIAffineTile`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIAffineTile) to do that.

Comment: I would just use two copies of the image and two image views, and slide them, with clipping.

Comment: @matt Thanks. I am using it already for onscreen drawing (CALayers). Just looking for "smarter" when saving to disk.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with CIFilter however the performance hit is 3-4x slower. However, the code is more readable.

```
- (CIImage *)image:(NSImage *)image shiftXBy:(CGFloat)shiftX YBy:(CGFloat)shiftY
{
    //avoid calling TIFFRepresentation here cause the performance hit is even bigger
    CIImage *ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithData:[image TIFFRepresentation]];
    CGAffineTransform xform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    NSValue *xformObj = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&xform objCType:@encode(CGAffineTransform)];
    ciImage = [ciImage imageByApplyingFilter:@"CIAffineTile"
                         withInputParameters:@{kCIInputTransformKey : xformObj} ];
    ciImage = [ciImage imageByCroppingToRect:CGRectMake(shiftX, shiftY, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
    return ciImage;
}
```

Comment: CIFilter is fast. Rendering to an NSImage is what’s slow.

Answer (score 0):

For optimum performance you need to use CALayer. Here’s the basic concept:

- Your `NSView` subclass should have `wantsLayer` and `layerUsesCoreImageFilters` set to `true`.
- Assign your image to `content` property of `NSView.layer` (or add a new sublayer).
- Create `CIAffineTile` filter and add it to the layer.

Now you can change values of the filter without reloading or redrawing the image. This all would be hardware accelerated.